# wait for promises.all() to finish a nested api call

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have got to call three APIS one after another with promises.all() at once based on result.

```
api1().toPromise().then(result=>{
 return result;
}).then(api1Result=>{
     api2(api1Result).toPromise().then(result2=>{
       // here I have to call three promises which return true or false
      let promises = []; 
      promises.push(addValue(result2));
      promises.push(moveItem(result2));

     Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
      console.log('done')
      return done;
     });
    }).then(promisesResult=>{
      console.log(promisesResult);
    });
 });
```

here, console.log(promisesResult) is undefined and appears before 'done' is consoled

I have tried

```
   Promises.all(promises).then(async function(values){
     await values
     return 'done'
    });
```

but it has no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `async/await`, you can just do:

```
const result1  = await api1().toPromise();
const result2  = await api2(result1).toPromise();  
const finalResults = await Promise.all([addValue(result2), moveItem(result2)]);
return finalResults;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to wrap the whole thing in a `Promise` which resolves once `Promise.all` completes:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
  api1()
    .toPromise()
    .then(api1Result => {
      api2(api1Result)
        .toPromise()
        .then(result2 => Promise.all([addValue(result2), moveItem(result2)]))
        .then(finalResult => {
          console.log("done");
          resolve(finalResult);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Adrice. Gave me a wonderful idea of what was wrong in the first place and it worked.